# uploading to amazon S3 - kohana

Tags: php, amazon-s3, kohana

Im building an app using kohana. I need to be able to upload files directly to S3. Can you advise on a S3 helper for kohana?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the [AWS PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/).

- It is not specific to kohana and will work on any platform.
- It is really easy to use, especially with S3.
- There is minimal setup, and it is really well documented.

Answer (score 5):

Someone wrote a module for Kohana using the AWS PHP SDK.
You can find it here : https://github.com/jylinman/kohana-aws